# how to make an image a clickable input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an image a clickable in put `type=file`
something like

```
 <label for="formFileSm" class="label_display form-label">avtar</label>

 <input class="width_input mx-auto form-control form-control-sm" id="formFileSm" type="file">

 <img src="photos/gamer.png" class="image_profile width_fix_35" alt="">
```

I tried to hide the input and add a click handler to img (but I didn't succeed )
I would appreciate the help of you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const img = document.getElementById('image');
  const file = document.getElementById('file');
  
  img.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    file.click();
  })
  
  // for getting the file event
  file.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // do whatever you want
    console.log('file selected', e.target.files[0]);
  });
})
```

```html
<img width="150" src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" id="image" />
<input type="file" id="file" style="display: none;" />
```

click event listener on the image and on the click fire the click event of the file input. Try this-

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `img` tag in the `label` and apply `display:none` to the input:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="formFileSm" class="label_display form-label">avtar <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="image_profile width_fix_35" alt="">
</label>

<input class="width_input mx-auto form-control form-control-sm" id="formFileSm" type="file">
```

Answer (score -1):

If I got the question right you are looking for a custom select.
You can follow the example here:

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Of course you can use and style an image as you need, changing css in this section:

```
/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

and using background-image: url("your_image");